# crm-menubar.css not loading after upgrade to 5.35.1

Tags: joomla, menu

My client's CiviCRM instance was 18 months out of date and we have finally bought it up to latest version Joomla (3.9.25) and CiviCRM (5.35.1).

I noticed the CiviCRM menu wasn't showing at the top of the page where it would usually be but it was displayed down the left hand side (and without styling). So I check if all of the css files were loaded and found `crm-menubar.XXXX.css` had a status of canceled.

Clicking the **Reset Paths** button brings a version of `menubar.XXXX.css` back for a while.

On further investigation `menubar.XXXX.css` is trying to be loaded from {Joomla_root}/media/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn/ folder. **Reset Paths** definitely creates the file in that folder but the scheduled task **Clean-up Temporary Data and Files** removes it.

Is there a way to get the `menubar.XXXX.css` to persist?

Comment: Can you check the template c directory path is correctly set in your civicrm.settings.php and its not a symlink?

Comment: @PradeepNayak I have checked that the civicrm.settings.php path is correct (both of them in this case since it's Joomla) and there is no symlink in the directory path to it.